# MotoG5s encryption switch "on" but doesn't ask for pin on restart

Tags: stock-android, encryption

I've had encryption turned on on my MotoG5s since I bought it last year. It used to ask for a pin every time it was turned on and at every restart.

Since updating to 7.x.x (currently on 7.1.1) it's never asked for this pin *but* the switch in settings says encryption is on.

Do people think my phone is encrypted? How can I check?

Answer (score 1):

An Android device can be encrypted without a PIN or password.

In such a case and if the encryption is "hardware based" the data is just bound to your device. The advantage of an encryption without PIN/password is that it can be erased very quick by just throwing away the key. No need to overwrite the all the data.

Therefore the question is not if or if not your device is encrypted - the question is what risk or attack do you expect the encryption to resist?

If you want to avoid other people to access your data when you loose your device you have to set a pin or password (not only because of the encryption). It will then also be used for the device encryption, making it harder for an attacker to access your data.

Comment: So I use a pin, but maybe I should make my question more clear. I use to have to enter a pin immediately after the phone turned on to get it to boot, but this process in not longer happening. I just get to the "normal" screen to enter your pin/unlock the phone.

Comment: Google introduced a new encryption scheme that does not require you to enter the PIN twice (at boot and then for device unlock again) - it is named file based encryption. You can check if your device uses file based encryption via `adb shell getprop ro.crypto.type` - it should output `file`.